# C# Mysql Parameters Issue

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, parameters, command

I'm trying to write a query to my database. When I originally wrote it I didn't use parameters, I am now trying to do so But I am getting a Mysql Error now.

> **Column count doesn't match value at row1**

Which in my 1st column I have an auto Incremented number labeled as "**ID**" Which I do not believe I have to add to the query because of the auto increment..

**This is the newly written code:**

```
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection);
            string Query = "INSERT INTO tasklist.tasks (TaskName, AssignedTo, StartDate, EndDate, Description, DirPath, Completed) VALUES (?TaskName),(?AssignedTo),(?StartDate),(?EndDate),(?Description),(?DirPath),(?Completed);";

            MySqlCommand insertCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);

            conn.Open();

            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?TaskName", txtTaskName.Text);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?AssignedTo", txtAssignTo.Text);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?StartDate", txtdateStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-M-d"));
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?EndDate", txtDateEnd.Value.ToString("yyyy-M-d"));
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Description", txtTaskDescription.Text);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?DirPath", txtDirPath.Text);
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Completed",("0"));

            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
```

Remember the previous way without parameters worked... however with parameters does not work. What exactly am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: When using .add VS states that `.add` is deprecated and to use `.AddWithValue`

Comment: Look more closely - it is the `.Add(object, object)` form that is deprecated.  `Parameters.Add("@p1", MySqlDbType.Foo).Value = varBar;`  Specifying the datatype prevents any misunderstanding or unwanted type conversions

Comment: I see, thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only one pair of parentheses around all parameters

```
INSERT INTO tasklist.tasks (TaskName, AssignedTo, StartDate, EndDate, Description, DirPath, Completed) 
VALUES (?TaskName, ?AssignedTo, ?StartDate, ?EndDate, ?Description, ?DirPath, ?Completed)
```

Comment: @Mokey, note that _all_ the values per row you're inserting are within `()` parentheses, not _each_ value.  If you were inserting 2 rows, the second set of values would also be contained, together, in another set.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out right before I came back to check. This is what I did.

`string Query = "INSERT INTO tasklist.tasks (TaskName, AssignedTo, StartDate, EndDate, Description, DirPath, Completed) VALUES ((?TaskName), (?AssignedTo), (?StartDate), (?EndDate), (?Description), (?DirPath), (?Completed));";` which fixed it

Comment: Sorry, I code a lot in SQF for A game called Arma 3. Redundant parentheses are common and needed in the language... Force of habit I guess. Will fix. Thanks for the constructive criticism.